# Does local reference to int provide any benefit?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, primitive-types

Consider following two code samples:

```
void int_fun(int val) {}

void another_fun() {
    vector<int> test(1, 1);
    const int& int_ref = test[0];
    int_fun(int_ref);
}
```

versus

```
void int_fun(int val) {}

void another_fun() {
    vector<int> test(1, 1);
    const int int_val = test[0];
    int_fun(int_val);
}
```

Is it true that compiler can implement int_ref as no op, while in second case it will have to create a copy of test[0]? Or copy can be optimized out in second case too, and these two samples are equivalent in performance?

Example and question is motivated by the fact that sometimes for code clarity it is beneficial to create local object that would be right away passed to some function like in example.

Does using reference for primitive types (such as int, bool, etc) provide any benefit in such case, or reference and value are equivalent (or perhaps value is even better)?

Comment: You could look at the assembly code. The compiler would probably remove everything.

Comment: Why do you need an extra reference to the variable in the first place? You could just write `int_fun(test[0])`.

Comment: @tobi303 You are right, it is for clarity only - sometimes function takes a lot of arguments, and each argument is of form var.GetAnotherVar().GetSomethingElse().value(), so it is easier to break it up a little - maybe it is just a personal preference.

Comment: If it was an object but not an int, it would definitely make a difference, as the constructore might have side effects

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, definitely - I will update the question

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, but that would be for specific compiler - I was looking if there is some general wisdom that can be  applied universally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the circumstances you give, I see little real advantage. I suspect most compilers would produce identical code for the two under most circumstances (at least with optimization enabled). I think the reference makes the intent a little more clear though: that the real intent is to pass the original object to the function, and you're just creating and passing an alias to that object for whatever reason.

Under slightly different circumstances, there could be a real difference in behavior though. The obvious one would be if the function received a reference:

```
void int_fun(int &val);

void another_fun() {
    vector<int> test(1, 1);
    int &int_val = test[0];
    int_fun(int_val);
}
```

In this case, `int_fun` might modify the value to which it received the reference, so if you created a reference, then passed that by reference, the references would be collapsed, so the function could modify the value in the array (but if you created a copy, then passed it by reference, the copy would be modified instead of the original).

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question with const to avoid this ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

The code sample that you are showing is a micro-optimization (or a micro-de-optimization, whatever the case may be) because the cost of making a single copy of a primitive is extremely cheap on modern hardware; same goes for making a reference to a primitive. The cost fades in comparison with the cost of invoking a function that does anything of interest.

However, a very simple change to your example demonstrates a situation when making a reference to a primitive becomes beneficial, because you can assign them back.

Here is your example modified to use `std::map<std::string,int>` in place of `std::vector<int>`:

```
std::map<std::string,int> cache;

int compute_new(int old) {
    return old+1;
}

void fun_with_ref(const std::string& key) {
    int& int_ref = cache[key];
    int_ref = compute_new(int_ref);
}

void fun_with_val(const std::string& key) {
    int int_val = cache[key];
    cache[key] = compute_new(int_val);
}
```

Note how `fun_with_ref` performs a single lookup by `key`, while `fun_with_val` requires two lookups. The access time of `std::map<std::string,ing>` grows as O(log<sub>2</sub>N), so the savings may become significant when the map grows to a large size.

A [quick micro-benchmark](http://ideone.com/0A2V5X) shows that the code that uses references with a map of 1,000,000 entries is nearly twice as fast as the code using values.

```
vector<string> keys;
for (int i = 0 ; i != 1000000 ; i++) {
    auto key = to_string(i);
    cache[key] = i;
    keys.push_back(key);
}
auto ms1 = duration_cast< milliseconds >(
    system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
).count();
for (const string& key : keys) {
    fun_with_ref(key);
}
auto ms2 = duration_cast< milliseconds >(
    system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
).count();
for (const string& key : keys) {
    fun_with_val(key);
}
auto ms3 = duration_cast< milliseconds >(
    system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
).count();
cout << "Ref: " << (ms2-ms1) << endl;
cout << "Val: " << (ms3-ms2) << endl;
```

Output:

```
Ref: 557
Val: 1064
```

Answer (score 0):

Code for clarity.  For non-trivial code, sometimes using a reference to a container member makes for clearer code.  Also, I may do this when passing in a smart pointer to a function.  Inside the function, I will dereference it once by assigning it to a reference and use that reference throughout the function.
What this does is make it clearer and avoid copying the object.  For built in types, I would just use an assignment and avoid the reference.

If you really need every once of performance, then you can look at assembly language code produced.  And after that, profile it.

Answer (score -1):

Using references to local values is sometimes useful, even if they are basic types, if they are inside more complex types, so that you can use the reference as a read/write shortcut to the real variable. The trick here is the *write* part. If there is no need to modify the variable, then copying the value is just as good.

Take for example a more convoluted code:

```
void fun()
{
     vector<int> test;
     //fill test with a lot of values
     for (int i=0; i < test.size(); ++i)
     {
         int &x = test[i]; //<-- handy reference!
         if (x > i)
             ++x;
         else if (x < i)
             --x;                
     }
}
```

If you want to write the same logic without the reference, you'd have to use the `vector::operator[](int)` at least twice!

Change the `vector` into a `map` and things are even more interesting:

```
void fun()
{
    map<string, int> keys;
    //fill keys
    int &x = keys["foo"];
    ++x;
}
```

Comment: This answer the question in the title when its taken literally, but OP was asking for possible difference in performance.

Comment: @tobi303: The difference in performance is obvious if you note that you are saving calls to external, possibly expensive, functions, such as `map::operator[]`.

Comment: you are making up your own examples, in the OPs code there is neither a map, nor do his two versions differ in the number of calls to "external" functions.